# shell_exec() in PHP doesn't execute my specific command

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm currently building a class in PHP that generates PDF documents using the [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) command line app.

To do this, I'm using a call to shell_exec to call the WKHTMLTOPDF executable. However, this particular call does not seem to be executed; it returns NULL almost instantly.

A small test I did gave me the following results:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('ping nu.nl'));
// This prints a string, containting the expected output of the ping command
var_dump(shell_exec('"c:/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe" --orientation "Landscape" --page-size "A2" --margin-top "25mm" --margin-left "20mm" --margin-bottom "20mm" --margin-right "20mm" "http://www.nu.nl/" "C:/Temp/1280310218.pdf"'));
// This prints NULL
```

So, `shell_exec()` seems to be working, also `safe_mode` is off, and pasting the full command into cmd.exe *does* run the command properly.

If the problem isn't in either of the above (safe mode, a faulty command, or `shell_exec()` itself) what else can it be? All I can think about is a user rights issue, but both the executable and the directory it's in have full access settings for every user group on my system.

(Note: Though I'm developing on a Windows machine, this code will run on a Linux server in production. Hence, windows-only solutions aren't what I'm looking for, unless ofcourse this problem itself turns out to be related to windows)

Comment: Have you tried 'manually' writing to `c:/temp/` to make sure the php process owner has the right to write there?

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: Just tested that, and it works perfectly. But even if it didn't I'd expect to see that in the result string returned by `shell_exec()`, since WKHTMLTOPDF warns me if files are not readable / writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions by create file using fopen() in temp dir.
Does it create pdf ? Maybe this program doesn't output to stdout, but stderr same as ffmpeg for example. Try adding "2>&1" after your command.

Or, this software uses some files in directory where is installed. Try first to change directory by adding something like "cd c:\wkhtmltopdf;YOUR_COMMAND"

Comment: Your first suggestion did the trick; Appearantly, quotes around the command to be executed (`"c:/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe"`) are not allowed, and that error was indeed stored in stderr. And to think I only added those quotes because the app was installed in `Program Files/` in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a php library to do that, which would be more efficient and integrated. There is for example [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default).

Comment: The reason I chose a CLI app, and not a PHP library, is because none of the ones I've checked offers us all the options we need; FPDF, DOMPDF, TCPDF among others, all were lacking in one way or another. WKHTMLTOPDF is by far the best and most complete solution. If it works, that is.

Answer (score -1):

remove these environment variable settings >>

```
"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and it should work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer on why you think this should work and how this fits the answer, what problems it solve by _removing these environment variable settings_?

Comment: he develops in Win and'll deploy on linux so no Mamp here